# findLast and findLastIndex not working / existing in codesandbox

Tags: javascript, typescript, codesandbox

In codesandbox for example `[1,2,3].findLastIndex(n => n === 2)` has an error saying that the method `findLastIndex` (I've checked and the same is true for `findLast`) does not exist on a number array. I've tried the same with other types of arrays and it;s the same.

It is not a browser problem since trying that in the browser console works.

Comment: Not an explanation, but `const res = [1,2,3].findLastIndex(n => n === 2);` is working well...

Comment: I'm getting the same error with typescript updated to the latest version.

Comment: This is a known issue, there is a temporary workaround in this discussion: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48829

Comment: So should i close this - mark it as answered or what?